# Is *issue a useful tag?

Tags: discussion

I doubt it very much - so would it be sensible to edit questions with that tag? Should I try to replace it with some other tag or just remove it from the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 2 questions only... Just remove them from the question and sort it out with something else.

Comment: Ack - seemed like a good start for retagging - but I don't understand "sort it out with something else" - do you mean replace it?

Comment: Remove or replace... Edit Edit Edit!